# Applying Transitions to more than one div classes

Tags: html, css

I want to apply transition to more than one div class.
I want to make an animated show so, I need to animate a lot of divs.
I have tried all possible sources on internet.

Here is my coding:

```
<html>
<head>

    <style>

    .line1 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        transition: width 2s;
    }
    div:hover {
        width:400px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class ="line1"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: There was a typo, now try adding those styles and try.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wr2ufbxu/2/)**

```
.line1 div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition: width 2s;
    margin:10px;
}
.line1 div:hover {
    width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to just create many divs with the same class.

```
<style>

.line1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition: width 2s;
}
    div :hover {
        width:400px;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="line1">
        <div class="line1">
        <div class="line1">
```

Or create multiple classes for different transitions:

```
.line1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition: width 2s;
}
.line2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    transition: width 2s;
}
.line3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    transition: width 2s;
}
    div :hover {
        width:400px;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="line1">
        <div class="line2">
        <div class="line3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this on codepen http://codepen.io/antoniskamamis/pen/hjBrE

It is a great example of using css only to do transitions between a serious of divs.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img class='photo'  src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8320/8035372009_7075c719d9.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo'  src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8517/8562729616_35b1384aa1.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo'  src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8465/8113424031_72048dd887.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo'  src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8562523343_9bb49b7b7b.jpg" alt="" />

</div>
```

CSS

```
body{background:#000;}
.container{
  margin:50px auto;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:10px solid;
  border-top-color:#856036;
  border-left-color:#5d4426;
  border-bottom-color:#856036;
  border-right-color:#5d4426;
  position:relative;

}
.photo{
  position:absolute;
  animation:round 16s infinite;
  opacity:0;

}
@keyframes round{   
  25%{opacity:1;}
  40%{opacity:0;}
} 

img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0s;}
img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:4s;}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:8s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:12s;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a Transition Class and a transition Hover class in CSS
In given code  Make Div tag (which you want to trns) member of Trans class `<div Class="Trans">`
Here is code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .Trans
        {
            margin:20px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            transition: width 2s;
            background: gray;
        }
        .normal
        {
            margin:20px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: gray;
        }
        Div.Trans:hover 
        {
            background: green;
            width:400px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div Class="Trans">Div Trans</div>
        <div class="normal" >Div_Normal</div>
        <div Class="Trans">Div Trans</div>
        <div class="normal" Div_Normal>Div_Normal</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Style

```
 .Trans //Style You need to apply on transition
        transition: width 2s;//Transition Statement Must be included in .Trans Class

 .normal //Normal Div you don't need if you dont want to apply any style
 .Div.Trans: Hover //Olly apply hover of a Div Which Having class of Trans
```

> You can check it in given code snippest

```css
.Trans {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 2s;
  background: red;
}
.normal {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
Div.Trans:hover {
  background: green;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div Class="Trans">Div_Trans</div>
  <div class="normal">Div_Normal</div>
  <div Class="Trans">Div_Trans</div>
  <div class="normal">Div_Normal</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding transitions to each class, add them all together in a comma separated list

```
.line1, .line2, .line3 {
    transition: 1s width ease;
}
```